# User name not refreshing after another user logs in

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0

In my blazor webassembly application I have
MainLayout.razor:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <LoginLogoutButton />
        </div>

        <div class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </div>
    </main>
</div>

@code
{
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

    }
}
```

Loginlogoutbutton.razor component:

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <span>Hello, @username</span>
        <button @onclick="Logout" class="btn btn-danger">Logout</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <button @onclick="Login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {

    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }
    
    void Login()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("login");
    }

    async Task Logout()
    {
        await AuthService.LogOut();
    }

    string username = string.Empty;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (authenticationStateTask is not null)
        {
            var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
            var user = authState?.User;

            if (user?.Identity is not null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                username = authState.User.FindFirst(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId)?.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and a login.razor page

```
<h3>Log in</h3>

@if (showAuthenticationError)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <p>@authenticationErrorText</p>
    </div>
}
<EditForm Model="model" OnSubmit="ExecuteLogin" class="card card-body bg-light mt-5">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <InputText id="username" @bind-Value="model.Email" class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>model.Email)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <InputText type="password" @bind-Value="model.Password" class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>model.Password)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private AuthenticationUserModel model = new();
    private bool showAuthenticationError = false;
    private string authenticationErrorText = string.Empty;

    private async void ExecuteLogin()
    {
        showAuthenticationError = false;
        var result = await AuthService.Login(model);
        if (result is not null)
        {
            NavManager.NavigateTo("/");
        }
        else
        {
            authenticationErrorText = "There was an error when trying to log in...";
            showAuthenticationError = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works good, except if I login as **user1**, then logout, then log in as **user2**, the username of *loginlogoutbutton* component is not updated from *user1* to *user2*, because *OnInitializedAsync* is not fired, although there's *NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged* call in my *AuthStateProvider*. I have to refresh browser to see the current user's name.
To make *OnInitializedAsync* called I must change *ExecuteLogin* method:

```
NavManager.NavigateTo("/", true); // true added
```

How to do it without full refresh?